# Google hreflang language confusion: Do I have to add hreflang for the page ITSELF?

Tags: html, seo, multilingual, google-search-console

On [Google's `hreflang` documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en), in the 2-language example, it says:

> Imagine you have an English language page hosted at
>   http://www.example.com/, with a Spanish alternative at
>   http://es.example.com/. You can indicate to Google that the Spanish
>   URL is the Spanish-language equivalent of the English page in one of
>   three ways:
>
> - **HTML link element in header.** In the HTML `<head>` section of http://www.example.com/, add a `link` element pointing to the Spanish
>     version of that webpage at http://es.example.com/, like this:
>
>   ```html
>   <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
>   ```

But in its 3-language example, it says:

> If you have multiple language versions of a URL, each language page
>   must identify all language versions, **including itself**.  For
>   example, if your site provides content in French, English, and
>   Spanish, the Spanish version must include a rel="alternate"
>   hreflang="x" link for itself in addition to links to the French and
>   English versions. Similarly, the English and French versions must each
>   include the same references to the French, English, and Spanish
>   versions.

The above is an example for a 3-language site. My website consists of only 2 languages - the default/main ENGLISH and THAI. Do I have to add the tag **for the page itself**? Google's documentation is not clear about this point and in its example for 2-language site, it is not mentioned.

For example, this is what I put in http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php

```html
<!-- GOOGLE INTERNATIONAL LANGUAGE TARGETING -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
</head>
```

Is the above correct? Or should I use:

```html
<!-- GOOGLE INTERNATIONAL LANGUAGE TARGETING -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to show them the English page for Chinese speaking users, you can indeed use your second example:

```
<!-- GOOGLE INTERNATIONAL LANGUAGE TARGETING -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
```

The new x-default hreflang attribute value signals to Google's algorithms that the page doesn’t target any specific language or locale and is the default page when no other page is better suited - [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.sg/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html)

Comment: My website has no Chinese version. So if a Chinese viewer is searching, I would want to show them the URLs of English version. I am sure most Chinese don't read in Thai. So I guess I will use back this second example.

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation page is somewhat lousy because they always refer to `hreflang="x"` where `x` is just a placeholder for a language tag. The language tag `x` on its own is not valid, as it [has](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47#section-2.1) to be followed by a hyphen and an alphanumeric string (`x-foo`):

> ```
> privateuse    = "x" 1*("-" (1*8alphanum))
> ```

So "[…] the Spanish version must include a `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` link for itself […]" doesn’t make sense.

`x-default` is such a (valid) private language tag, and if you want to follow Google’s interpretation of it, `x-default` should only be used [for language-independent pages that serve as language selectors/redirectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187198/1591669).

So neither of your examples is correct.

You should either

- include only the link to the translation:

  ```html
  <!-- on the English page <http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php> -->
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
  ```
- or include both, the link to the translation and the self-referencing link:

  ```html
  <!-- on the English page <http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php> -->
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
  ```

It is beyond me why Google would recommend to have a self-referencing `alternate` link in the first place, and assuming that it makes any sense, why they don’t recommend this self-referencing link in case of only two languages.

HTML5 defines that the [`alternate` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate) references "an alternate representation of the current document". So, using `alternate` for a link to the current document doesn’t make sense, because it’s not an "alternate representation of the current document", it *is* the current document.

Comment: Although I don't quite understand the use of x-default, I decided to use the second example and remove all <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/en/xxxxx.php"> Thanks for your direction.

Comment: @LawrenceL.: You could use `x-default` [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187198/1591669) for linking to `http://janwawa.com/`: a page that *a)* is not specific to one language, and *b)* serves as a language selector page.

Comment: I am getting more confused. This is what I want to do actually:

If the viewer's language is neither English or Thai (in this example the viewer's language is Chinese), I want the viewer to go to the English page.

Meaning, 

English viewers go to English page.
Thai viewers go to Thai page.
Chinese or any other Non-English/Non-Thai viewers go to English page.

So isn't my tags should be:
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/en/mypage.php">

Comment: Shouldn't I be using the second example (3 lines of tags) in my original question?

Comment: @LawrenceL.: This markup has nothing to do with automatically redirecting users. It just tells: *this* is translation of *this* document in *this* language. How you decide to redirect users is up to you. When Chinese users visit the Thai version, it’s generally a bad idea to automatically redirect them to the English version (as they would have no chance to see the Thai version if they decide to). So you just offer a language switcher. Now, for your front page, you can use `x-default` as this page is not language-specific, right? So on this page, you could redirect freely, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with Unor that it is not clear *why* Google recommend to use a self-referencing alternate `link`, [Google's advice (2017)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) is a clear statement:

> If you have multiple language versions of a URL, each language page should identify different language versions, including itself.

For languages or locales not specified by alternate links [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) says:

> For the default page that doesn’t target any specific language or
>   locale, add rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default".

So, I would use *another* URL here.

Additionally, I would also recommended to add a `canonical` link to each page.

**Examples**

Your English page could look like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
<!-- Alternate links are the same for all pages  -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/default/contact.php">
```

Your Thai page could look like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<!-- Alternate links are the same for all pages  -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="th" href="http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://janwawa.com/default/contact.php">
```