# Semantic use of hreflang and lang attribute

Tags: html, multilingual, semantic-markup, hreflang

This is *not* a SEO question.

I am curious how to markup HTML in a semantic correct way concerning the used language. Please correct me if my markup is mistaken.

My questions is: do I need the `lang` attribute in the `html` tag when I already use the `hreflang` attribute in the `link` tag?

Are both directives semantically different? I mean: will the self-reference in the `link` tag in both examples semantically be understood as indicating the language of the document?

The code samples below might clarify my question a bit:

**Example of an English webpage**

`http://example.com/en/`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
     <title>English webpage</title>
     <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default">
</head>
<body>
     <p>This is a webpage written in English. 
        This page is also available in Dutch. 
        The default language of this page is English. 
</body>
</html>
```

**Example of a Dutch webpage**

`http://example.com/nl/`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl"> 
<head>
     <title>Nederlandse webpagina</title> 
     <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/nl">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="en">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl">
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default">
</head>
<body>
     <p>Dit is een Nederlandstalige web pagina. 
        Deze pagina is beschikbaar in het Engels. 
        De standaardtaal van deze pagina is Engels.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always provide the `lang` attribute on the `html` element.

Two reasons relevant to your case:

- The HTML spec describes [how the language of a node gets determined](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/dom.html#language). The `hreflang` attribute plays no role here.

  If you don’t provide `lang` on the `html` element, **this node has no  language.**
- An [`alternate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/links.html#link-type-alternate)+`hreflang` link is only interpreted to point to a translation of the current document if the value of `link`-`hreflang` differs from the value of `html`-`lang`:

  > If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute’s value differs from the root element’s language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

  If you don’t provide `lang` on the `html` element, **the `alternate`+`hreflang` links are not considered to point to translations.**

---

Even if a user agent deduces the language of the document by taking self-referential¹ `alternate`+`hreflang` links into account, there are situations in which this could fail:

- If the HTML document gets opened locally, it no longer has a HTTP URL, so a user agent can’t deduce that the `alternate`+`hreflang` link refers to this document.
- If the HTML documents gets retrieved over a different URL (e.g., with tracking parameters), the `alternate`+`hreflang` link no longer refers to the current URL, so a user agent can’t deduce that it does apply to this URL, too.

(With a `canonical` link, both situations could be mitigated, but that’s one more thing a user agent would have to support. Not all do.)

---

¹ Strictly speaking, a self-referential `alternate`+`hreflang` hyperlink is not semantic, because [`alternate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html51-20171003/links.html#link-type-alternate) is defined to refer to "an alternate representation of the current document", but a document is of course not an *alternate* representation of itself. However, as [Google Search documents its use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636822/1591669), it’s now common to see this markup.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.